# Blocks in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have started use Parse (which I downloaded using Cocoapods) in a practice iOS application and I having a little bit of trouble understanding certain concepts.

I have written this code so far:

```
- (IBAction)saveUserButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    PFObject *loginCredentials = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"LoginCredentials"];
    loginCredentials[@"name"] = self.usernameTextField.text;
    loginCredentials[@"password"] = self.passwordTextField.text;


    [loginCredentials saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if(error.code == kPFErrorConnectionFailed){
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please check you connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];
        }else if(succeeded && !error){
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" message:@"Your object saved" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];
        }else if(error){
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

    }];
}
```

My main question I have is what is the purpose of using saveInBackGroundWithBlock. Could I do the same logic by doing:

```
[loginCredentials saveInBackground];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" message:@"Your object saved" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alertView show];
```

Is the block only helpful if we want to have access to the succeeded and error variables?

Comment: [Block Programming Topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Comment: haha thanks that was actually very helpful. I understood now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in  `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` the save operation is executed in a background thread not in the main thread(thread used by UI ), once it ends executing it calls back the block to execute it. Not using the main thread for this save-operation makes the user-interface responsive while executing the save in another thread.

you can make the save operation in the main thread by using save method and then show alert based on success, but you will completely block the user interface and its not a best practice unless its necessarily to continue on the app.

```
bool succeeded = [loginCredentials save];
```

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous calls will execute code on the main thread (UI thread), which will prevent the UI from responding to user events.  This is generally considered bad practice because it gives the user the impression that your app has frozen when in fact one thread can't do two things at once.  Therefore, you typically use asynchronous calls (blocks) to execute complex code on background threads, freeing the UI to continue performing some operation so the user isn't confused or just left hanging waiting on the operation to finish.

Looking at the PFObject spec, the `– saveInBackground` and `– saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` methods are the asynchronous options. In this case, the callback block is just reporting whether or not the operation was successful, and includes an `NSError` object for reporting in case it failed.

That all being said, I *think* you can save the object using your code, but you will not get the opportunity to respond to any errors that arise in the process.  Meaning, you are making an assumption that your object saved successfully when you are creating and presenting the alert view.

I'm basing this opinion on the `saveInBackground` method implementation, which is just returning a `BFTask` object:

```
- (BFTask *)saveInBackground {
    return [self.taskQueue enqueue:^BFTask *(BFTask *toAwait) {
        return [self saveAsync:toAwait];
    }];
}
```

Here's the object documentation on the two methods from Parse:

> – saveInBackground
>
> Saves the PFObject asynchronously.
>
> - (BFTask PF_GENERIC ( NSNumber *) *)saveInBackground
>
> Return Value
>
> The task that encapsulates the work being done.
>
> Declared In PFObject.h
>
> – saveInBackgroundWithBlock:
>
> Saves the PFObject asynchronously and executes the given callback block.
>
> - (void)saveInBackgroundWithBlock:(PF_NULLABLE PFBooleanResultBlock)block
>
> Parameters
>   block
>
> The block to execute. 
>   It should have the following argument signature: ^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error).
>
> Declared In PFObject.h

If you aren't interested in handling the errors, and your objects are sufficiently simple to save, have you considered just using one of the synchronous save methods, like `- (BOOL)save` or `- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error`?  You could immediately respond to the BOOL value that is returned, in similar fashion to the Parse example you posted above (inside the completion block).

Comment: If I only use - (BOOL) save then it will block the user interface correct?

Comment: That is correct.  Again, this may or may not be acceptable depending on how sophisticated your object is.  Asynchronous calls will add some overhead to your process, so you need to make sure its worth the additional processing effort to use them.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb (that I go by), any time you are saving an object to a remote service you should use a block because network conditions vary so widely.  If you are saving a VERY simple object locally using a SQLite DB or Core Data, etc., then you can do it synchronously.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Thank you for sharing. Will definitely keep that in mind.